# How can I wait for an async operation without await async in React hooks and JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

Consider this JSX:

```
import { useConfig } from 'config'

const MyComponent = () => {

   const [items, setItems] = useState([])
   const { getConfigValue } = useConfig()

   return <div>
      {
          items.map(item => <div>{getConfigValue(item)}</div>)
      }
   </div>
}
```

And let's say our hook's code is:

```
const useConfig = () => {
    const getConfigValue = (key) => {
       // getting configuration items from API
    }

    return {
        getConfigValue
    }
}
```

As you can see, in my JSX I need to call a hook's function, and inside that function I need to first load some data from API and then return the value. Loading data from API is async. Let's say I'm using `fetch` or `axios`.

If I use `await` inside the `getConfigValue` funciton, then I need to mark it as async, then I need to await it inside my JSX, which is not permitted. My code won't compile.

What should I do?

Comment: Loading `async` data is often a mix of `useState` and `useEffect`

Answer (score 2):

There is a handy third-party package to handle cases like these called `use-async-effect`. The basic premise being that it operates like the traditional `useEffect` hook but allows async/await operations.

For your use-case, it would probably look something like this...

```
import { useAsyncEffect } from 'use-async-effect'
import { useConfig } from 'config'

const MyComponent = () => {
   const [items, setItems] = useState([])
   const [configs, setConfigs] = useState([])
   const { getConfigValue } = useConfig()

   useAsyncEffect(async () => {
      const values = await Promise.all(items.map(i => getConfigValue(i)))
      setConfigs(values)
   }, [items, getConfigValue])

   return <div>
      {
          items.map((_item, idx) => <div>{configs.at(idx)}</div>)
      }
   </div>
}
```

using `.at(idx)` here handles the cause of out of bounds indexing by just returning undefined, but could also be mitigated by added a length check or something of the sort.

---

Or you can split them up into separate components which may be cleaner:

```
import { useAsyncEffect } from 'use-async-effect'
import { useConfig } from 'config'

const MyComponent = () => {
   const [items, setItems] = useState([])

   return <div>
      {
          items.map((item, i) => <MyItem key={i} item={item} />)
      }
   </div>
}

const MyItem = ({ item }) => {
    const [config, setConfig] = useState(undefined)
    const { getConfigValue } = useConfig()

    useAsyncEffect(async () => {
        const value = await getConfigValue(item)
        setConfig(value)
    }, [item, getConfigValue])

    return <div>{config}</div>
}
```